# Can Amazon Web Services (AWS) be used for huge databases?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services

I have a project that requires the storage of several dozens of `TBs` of data. At first, few `TBs` of data will be stored. Then, the data is expected to grow at a pace of `5 GB` per day.

Based on business logic, I am able to split this across `10,000s` of files / tables (each file / table will consist of data of size ~ `1 [GB]`).

(**Note:** at any given point in time, only `10-20 [GB]` (say, 20 tables) are considered `hot data` that I'll actively query against.)

Can [Amazon Web Services (AWS)](http://aws.amazon.com/) be used to store & query such huge amount of data?

If instead I'd like to store this data in-house, what is the best way to approach this 
(for instance, it is clear that I cannot have all of the data on one machine etc...)?

Comment: What database are you planning to use Amazon's SimpleDB? SQL hosted on EC2? Something else? Also, what is the basis of your assertion that this data can not be one machine?

Comment: I'm planning to use `MySQL` or `SQLite`. How can dozens (say, `50`) of TBs be stored on one machine?

Comment: The same way that 1 byte can be stored on one machine, on the hard drive or disk array.

Comment: Let's assume that a disk size is ~ 2[TB]. Are you suggesting to have 25-40 disks of ~ 2[TB] size on ONE MACHINE?

Also, what about redundancy & performance? how can one machine handle possibly 100s of reads & writes at the same time?

Comment: Okay, now you are confusing storage with bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Lacking information about data format, schema, etc, here's how I'd handle it:

- store the data in S3 in some Map/Reduce friendly format
- use hadoop (or Elastic Map Reduce) to query the entire dataset when needed. Typical pattern is to use M/R to get all the answers you need ahead of time and store the much smaller results in some other database.
- If there's really a need to have 20GB of 'hot data' in SQL, I'd probably have some ETL for loading into Amazon RDS (MySQL), but I'd try to avoid it if I could use M/R to answer all my questions and have a small and optimized data set.

Answer (score 0):

Storage won't be the issue. Amazon's cloud is just computers (virtual) in another location. So the fact that it is in Amazon's cloud doesn't really change the performance equation really unless you are pulling down huge data sets into an app that is outside that cloud.

Transferring the 5GB of data in per day is likely to be the more thorny issue, but it seems doable.

Comment: Thanks. Using `Amazon`, can I really query against this huge database (with dozens of TBs in size), and expect good performance? The transfer of `5GB` per day is not an issue -- as the `5GB` will be generated by `EC2` instances.

Comment: Amazon is a red herring. It is just a remote computer. You should be asking this about whatever DB platform you intend to use. This is kind of like asking whether a Dell computer can handle such a huge database.

Comment: JohnFx, thank you. So perhaps the question becomes -- what hardware does one need in order to support such requirements? what is the right way to go? of course, I will only be using `Linux` systems (preferably, `Ubuntu`)

Comment: That is a very complicated question that would require me knowing a lot more about your usage scenarios and service level requirements. Probably not something we would be able to cover in a Q&A forum easily.

Comment: @user3262424 If you only use Linux / Ubuntu, you arleady are dead. Typically stuff like that runs either on Db2 on somee VMS variant on a mainframe, or uses Oracle ExaData appliances.

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not think. Not for hugh databases.

Those are the areas where you buy special hardware - for example Oracle ExaData (my last data warehouse had 20.000gb and that was small in their terms).

The problem is:

- Backups. Yes, Amazon sometimes looses data - happened.
- Loading hugh amounts of data.
- Resources. You likely need a LOT more than even their best virtual machines. Tuning that is a pain if you do not control the hardware.
- Cost. Really. Anything up 24/7 is expensive at amazon.

If it can be map/recude enabled or something like that - yes. Buta 96 core Oracle RAC install (which is small in Exadata terms) is not something I would like to try on Amazon.

And then they dont ahve the special hardware. Like Oracle ExaData RAID controllers that already filter out unneeded rows (by use of their storage index).

So, I would say: no.